# How to filter a datagrid with objects C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` that is filled with objects, now I want a search/filter-function for this `DataGrid`. I'm trying to use a textbox where you can enter a textstring and in my head a want to match this string against all the object fields (for example if the objects are Emails, I want to match the string against the Subject field) in the DataGrid.

If it is to any help the `DataGrid.DataSource` is declared like this (don't worry about the methods, the problem is the filter/search-function):

```
var newMess = LM.GetNewMessages();
if (newMess.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < newMess.Count; i++)
    {
        LM.InboxTemp.Insert(0, newMess[i]);
    }
}
BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = LM.InboxTemp; //List with Objects
dgNewMess.DataSource = source;
dgNewMess.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dgNewMess.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dgNewMess.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dgNewMess.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to filter collection of Emails, you can use Linq for that. Also you can use `ForEach` method of `List<Email>` to insert new filtered emails to your `InboxTemp` list:

```
string filter = txtFilter.Text;
LM.GetNewMessages()
  .Where(msg => msg.Subject.Contains(filter))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(msg => LM.InboxTemp.Insert(0, msg));
```

*UPDATE* with [Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView](http://blw.sourceforge.net/) you can assign datasource this way

```
dgNewMess.DataSource = new BindingListView<Email>(LM.InboxTemp);
```

and later apply filter

```
string filter = txtFilter.Text;
BindingListView<Email> emails = (BindingListView<Email>)dgNewMess.DataSource;
emails.Filter = new PredicateItemFilter<Email>(msg => msg.Subject.Contains(filter));
```

Comment: The list I have is already filled with objects (emails), and this list is connected to the DataGrid. I dont want to insert new objects to the list, I just want to be able to show the filtered objects depending on what search-criteria (from the textbox) is. Do I need to use a different DataSource for the filtered objects? Or can I use the same?

Comment: @user1789325 what you are doing in your sample code is inserting emails to list without filtering.Do you want to filter data, which already assigned to GridView? BTW is it WinForms or what?

Comment: Yes it's WinForms. Exactly, the DataGrid is already filled with Emails from a List

Comment: If your underlying emails list do not implement `IBindingListView` interface, then you can't just filter binding source like this `source.Filter("Subject LIKE 'Foo%')` - either filter `InboxTemp` and create new binding source, or use something like http://blw.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  this project: [DataGridView Filter Popup](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup)